# PIC16: How does one enter sleep mode using C?

Tags: pic

The [datasheet of my PIC16](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41364E.pdf) refers to the "`SLEEP` instruction". I'm programming the PIC16 in C using MPLAB X and the XC8 compiler.

How can I execute a `SLEEP` instruction on my PIC16 using C?

Comment: You should try looking into the [user manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/52053B.pdf) of your compiler, next time. Page 276.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this macro:

```
SLEEP();
```

> This macro is used to put the device into a low-power standby mode.

If you search for the definition of SLEEP() in the header files, you'll find:

```
#define SLEEP()     asm("sleep")
```

`asm();` is a statement which allows you to inline assembly instructions into your C code.

Comment: we should make sure to turn off WDT in that case.

Comment: @sandundhammika True, unless we purposely want the WDT to wake the PIC and resume execution when the time-out occurs